# What constitutes a computer being Core i7? Does it must have quad core?

Tags: cpu, intel-core-i7

I just bought the Dell XPS 13 9350 (Skylake) touch version i7.

I thought it was going to have quad core but it says 2 cores and 4 logical processors.

My question is, why is this device an i7 if it does not have quad core?

My old Lenovo ideapad has the same 2 cores and 4 logical processors but it is an i5. My assumption is that i7 does not necessarily mean quad cores. Below I have put the specs of my laptop.

`Processor - Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-6500U CPU @ 2.50GHz, 2592 Mhz, 2 Core(s), 4 Logical Processor(s)`

Comment: You are correct in your assumption that it does not necessarily mean it has four cores. **i7** is only a marketing designation

Comment: After reading https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_Core#Core_i7, do you still have any specific questions?

Comment: [Your CPU is a dual-core processor which supports hyperthreading](http://ark.intel.com/products/88194/Intel-Core-i7-6500U-Processor-4M-Cache-up-to-3_10-GHz).  As for finding out the reason, the processor isn't a quad-core processor, only Intel would be able to provide you the actual reason.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"i7" is just a model name given to a range of processors; it does not designate what the chip's capabilities actually are.

So as you assume, not all i7's are quad core.  Specifically, as with yours, the 6th Generation "U" models (which stands for 'Ultra-low power') are all dual core.

You can see which are, and are not, by checking out Intel's ARK web site.

I.E.:

4th Gen i7's: http://ark.intel.com/products/family/75023/4th-Generation-Intel-Core-i7-Processors#@All

6th Gen i7's: http://ark.intel.com/products/family/88392/6th-Generation-Intel-Core-i7-Processors#@All

Answer (score 1):

i7 is simply a brand name from Intel to specify the processor is in the higher end category. There is no way to tell how many cores it will have from this identifier alone, and could by anywhere from 2 to 12.

The only assumptions you CAN make from Core i7 processors are (at time of writing):

- Turbo boost
- Hyperthreading (you will see double the amount of logical cores vs physical cores).
- At least two physical cores

You cannot be certain from the i7 badge alone of how many cores it will have, or whether it will actually outperform high end i5 models, as there are a wide range of variables associated with each actual model.